# What is past tense of I will be

Tags: past-tense

What is the past tense of the sentence:

> I will be there

.

Comment: You should be able to find the answer by looking it up in a grammar or a dictionary: _I was there_.

Comment: @OliverMason Well, arguably no. The past tense version of *I will be there* is *I would be there*!

Comment: @Araucaria Depends how you interpret it: I see it as part of _I was there_ / _I am there_ / _I will be there_. If you see future as hypothetical, then you are right, as can be seen by _"I will be there"_ -- _I said I would be there_.

Comment: Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has two tenses: present "will" and preterite "would". Semantically, it is used to make reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe) but also for expressing volition (as in "I keep telling my son to get his hair cut, but he won't; so I've told him he has to" --- notice, the refusals to get his hair cut are in the PAST, and this sentence actually entails that there IS a haircut in his future!).

Comment: In some contexts, _I was to be there_ is the best option.

Comment: Verbs, not sentences, have tenses. And in modern treatments, not many. So 'I will be there' uses the 'will + V' construction to indicate a future time-frame, but is not an example of a 'future tense' (which English, unlike say French, does not possess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I was there"

OR

> "I was there at [a specific time]"

"I would be there" is saying "I can't make it to a location", e.g.

> "I would be there if I was able to" (present/future)

OR

> "I would have been there if I was able to" (past)

Comment: I will be there today at four even though yesterday I said I would be there at three.